# Evaluate $\sum_{r\in R^*}^{}{r^2}$ and prove that $R$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, finite-fields, symmetric-polynomials

I have some trouble with the following exercise:

> Let $R$ be a finite commutative ring s.t. $|R| = k$. Assuming
> $$ x^k-x=\prod_{r\in R}(x-r) \in R[x]$$
> how can we prove that $R$ is a field and evaluate $\sum_{r\in R^*}^{}{r^2}$?

To do so, first I proved that $x^{k-1}-1=\prod_{r\in R^*}(x-r)$. But then using elementary symmetric polynomial I had to prove that

$$\sum_{r\in R^*}^{}{r}=0 \text{ and } \prod_{r\in R^*}^{}{r}=(-1)^k.$$

I tried to evaluate every $e_i$ for the $k-1$ elements of $R^*$ but
I'm not sure about how I can proceed and don't really see how it can help to compute $\sum_{r\in R^*}^{}{r^2}$.

Thanks in advance for any help it would be a lot appreciated. Best wishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $r_0 \in R^*$, $$r_0 \left((-1)^k\prod_{r\in R^*\setminus \{r_0\}} r\right) = (-1)^k\prod_{r \in R^*} r = 1,$$ so $r_0$ is invertible with $r_0^{-1} = (-1)^k\prod_{r\in R^*\setminus \{r_0\}} r$.  Therefore $R$ is a field.

---

For the other question, we can note that (since $R^*$ is closed under the bijection $x \mapsto -x$)
$$(x^{k-1}-1)^2 = \left(\prod_{r \in R^*} (x-r)\right)\left(\prod_{r \in R^*} (x+r)\right) \\ x^{2k-2} - 2x^{k-1} + 1 = \prod_{r \in R^*} (x^2-r^2)$$
so $-\sum_{r \in R^*} r^2$ is the coefficient of $x^{2k-4}$ in $x^{2k-2} - 2x^{k-1} + 1$.

To answer this, we have some cases

- If $k-1 = 2k-4 \iff k=3$, then $\sum_{r\in R^*} r^2 = 2$.
- If $0 = 2k-4 \iff k=2$, then $\sum_{r\in R^*} r^2 = -1$
- Otherwise, $\sum_{r\in R^*} r^2 = 0$.

Comment: +1, but I'm not quite sure about your argument in the first sentence, since nilpotent elements of degree 2 may not be accounted for. for instance, the product of all non-zero elements of $\mathbb{Z}\big/4\mathbb{Z}$ is non-zero, but of course this ring is not an integral domain. similarly for $\mathbb{F}_2[x]\big/(x^2)$.

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Good point.  We'd need to know that the product the squares of the nonzero elements is nonzero.  We certainly have that, but at that point, it's easier to appeal to the fact the product of the nonzero elements is a unit, and then there's no need to go through the "finite integral domain" intermediate step (part of me is sad I can't include that ;-) )

Comment: my bad .. you're right